# Struggling to store data from file in an 2D int array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, constructor, nested-loops

I'm working on a project where I'm supposed to be reading sets of parameters from a txt file to then print multiple circles within the command prompt. Here is the format of the file:

> 10 10 14 15
>
> 50 20 5 15

This is just the constructor I've made for the Circle Class, but while it seems to read the file properly, something must be going wrong with my nested for loops. I ran the program with it printing what it was reading from the file during the loops and then what was stored after and it only seems to be saving the last two numbers of the first line (the array seems to hold 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15). This is only my second semester working on C++, so I can't help but wonder if there's something obvious I'm missing, but I could use some help here trying to figure out what's wrong with my loops/array so I can fix it and move on to the printing of the circles code which I'm also struggling with and running out of time to wrap my head around.

```
        Circle::Circle(string fileAdd)      //constructor function
    {
        int num;        //variable for holding the file data in loops
        cirCount = 0;       //making sure this variable doesn't have junk value
        cirStats = nullptr;     //making sure this variable doesn't have junk value
        string line;
        ifstream userFile;      //creating a filestream object
        userFile.open(fileAdd);    //opening the file
        if (userFile.is_open())     //confirming the file has properly been opened
        {
            while (getline(userFile, line))     //the number of circles is stored in a separate variable by this loop
            {
                if (line.length() != 0)     //this if statement checks whether the line is blank or not, and skips it if that's the case
                {
                    cirCount++;
                }
            }
            userFile.clear();
            userFile.seekg(0);
            cirStats = new int[STATS, cirCount];    //a dynamically allocated array is created in order to store the file data
            for (int i = 0; i < cirCount; i++)      //these nested loops store the data in a 2 dimensional array
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < STATS; j++)
                {
                    userFile >> num;
                    cirStats[j, i] = num;
                }
            }
            userFile.close();       //the file is closed to prevent issues down the line
            cout << cirCount << endl;
        }
        //if the file has not been properly loaded, then this code will run and exit the program
        else
        {
            cout << "User file failed to load. Please reset and try again.";
            exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cirCount; i++)      //these nested loops are just for testing what has been saved in the array
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < STATS; j++)
            {
                cout << cirStats[j, i] << endl;
            }
        }
    
    };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you have posted is neither complete (so we can't run it without filling in a lot of blanks) nor minimal (in that most if this code is probably not involved in the bug, and could be removed). At a guess I'd say the problem is that you're using `getline` and the stream input operator `>>` and they're coming into conflict.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`? Or did you not yet learn about that? You have a main misunderstaing of 2d arrays here. There must be only one value in the brackets[]. Comma will not work here . . .

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in @Armin_Montigny's comment. Instructions like

```cpp
cirStats[j, i] = num;
```

should, in fact, be written this way:

```cpp
cirStats[j][i] = num;
```

that is, without the comma operator.